# Create Customized role in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I wish to create a user with customized role in GCP for a Project

Roles were :

**user can:**

```
able to ssh all the servers in the project
monitor all the servers in the project 
list all  snapshots  in the project 
list all images in the project
```

**User should don't have :**

```
stop/delete the instances
view billing access
launch new instances
create/delete snapshot 
create/delete images
create/remove firewall tags
```

Is it possible ?

If so what are all the permissions needs to be added under customized role

Comment: read the docs on custom IAM roles and you'll find what you're looking for: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Graham Polley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877278/graham-polley), you can definitely use the custom role to set permission according to your use case. You need to find appropriate permission and set accordingly. You can find this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) that guides on how to create and manage custom roles. Note that, not all permissions are supported for the custom role. You can find the list of permissions and its associated support level (Supported, Testing, Not Supported) at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/custom-roles-permissions-support).